# Who was Krusenstern's scandalous priest?

Tags: russia, church

Krusenstern, captain of the first Russian circumnavigation, wrote a refined book on the voyage. He visited Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky in about 1804 and remarked without any further detail that "The priest of St. Peter and St. Paul was a scandal to his profession".

One of Krusenstern's officers, Löwenstern, noted in his journal that the captain was disappointed that the priest did not perform a vespers service on board.

Petropavlovsk had no church from 1767 to about 1800. The parish returned to its original seat after the typhus epidemic of 1799 killed off a lot of (Krusenstern says all) the population in nearby Paratunka. According to I. V. Viter, the "Salvation" church was being rebuilt in 1800.

Who was the scandalous priest?

Comment: Q: close voters, what is the problem?

Comment: As with your previous question about Hagemeister's journals, this question is likely one that cannot be answered without primary research and as such is very unlikely to be answered here.

Comment: Thank you. "Unlikely to be answered" is not one of the listed reasons to close.

Answer (score 1):

The church in nearby Paratunka continued to serve the area as the new Petropavlovsk church was under construction for a long time. Fedorova described it as "being built" in 1779; it was consecrated in 1810, and the chapel rebuilt in 1814, per *Камчатский краеведческий музей*; Peard found it "nearly finished" in 1827, with the clergyman still residing at Paratunka. In 1787 de Lesseps identified the local priest as Feodor Vereschagin, who had replaced his older brother Romanoff. Beechey didn't meet the priest when Peard did in 1827, but identified him as the descendant, instead of brother, of the earlier priest. I conclude that in 1804 the scandalous priest was a Vereschagin, probably Feodor.